# Is there a way to debug (iPhone) while running Leaks?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, memory-leaks

I'm running a debug build on the iPhone with Leaks.  I'd like to break at certain points to see if particular leaks have occurred yet.  This would allow me to narrow down where the leak is occurring by process of elimination.  However, the debugger is ignored while Leaks is running. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Run in debug mode as usual, then run Leaks separately.  You can attach Leaks to the running app using the Default Target drop-down list at the top of the app's window.  Just select the process that's the same name as your iPhone app (i.e. PushAndPop in the screenshot).

[Leaks screenshot http://www.17feet.com/external/screen_leaks.png](http://www.17feet.com/external/screen_leaks.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you launch it in debug mode first (cmd-Y), you can then open Instruments and choose the Leaks template and attach to your running iPhone app process.

Comment: I don't see any running processes to attach to.  Do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

a quick way to do that: open Terminal.app, run "ps axwww | grep Simulator/User/Applications | grep -v grep" (without the quotes), the first number is the PID (process ID of your running application) and then run "leaks PID" (without the quotes and replace PID with the first number got with the previous command)